# Framework for Deploying Android Web Apps as .JAR

Tags: java, web-applications, cordova, frameworks, web

I know that the PhoneGap framework can distribute web applications as .apk, but I need to distribute the application as a .JAR.

Is there any solution for this? I know that Java has ScriptEngine and Webview, but I want a framework that's similar to PhoneGap.

Comment: I don't understand the question! Youll have to try to rephrase it please

Comment: idk. i ask the question properly. but moderator change my question to arabic. thanx mod? :D

Comment: a moderator turn my question to arabic. another moderator block that question for being arabic. what in the world happened to u guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) and [Vaadin touch](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/touchkit), if I understand your question correctly

Comment: that's a great tools. but
- webview : code in java. web via url
- vaadin : code in java. web via code
- phonegap : code in html css js